# How to alter a column to accept values in some specific format?

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints

My table has a column that shows the phone number and I want to add a constraint where this number must be in a specific format like `+cod.country-cod.local-num.local`. For example: `'+54-351-4350114'`.

And later I want to add a constraint where `num.local` must have at least 7 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are looking for a [Postgres `CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html): such constraint does accept a regexp, with the `SIMILAR TO` operator:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT phone_number_check CHECK(
    phone_number SIMILAR TO '\+\d+-\d+-\d{7,}'
)
```

Regexp explanation:

```
\+        the + sign
\d+       at least one digit
-         the - sign
\d+       at least one digit
-         the - sign
\d{7,}    at least 7 digits
```

This will allow values like `'+54-351-1234567'`, while, for example rejecting `'+54-351-123456'`. You can freely adapt the regexp to your exact requirement, using [Postgres Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q7obH2dKRgW55q2S5YraAn/1)**

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to give names to each part of the phone number? For example: ```+cod.country-cod.local-num.local```